# Swift: How to adjust width of Date Picker with mode set to Time Only

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uidatepicker

There seems to be some wasted space towards the right of the date picker component:

[image]

And it doesn't matter if I increase or decrease the value of width/height of its frame; it stays the standard size.

```
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 500, height: 200))
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    view.addSubview(datePicker)
```

My question is, can it be adjusted?

edit: So I managed to find its short form but thats only addable through the storyboard.

Heres the view:

[image]

The top first picker is added programmatically and the second via storyboard. For some reason, I'm unable to make the programmatically created picker smaller...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just ask the date picker which size is sufficient ;)

**Option A**

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

// Let it size itself to its preferred size
datePicker.sizeToFit()
// Set the frame without changing the size
datePicker.frame = .init(x: 20, y: 100, width: datePicker.bounds.size.width, height: datePicker.bounds.size.height)

view.addSubview(datePicker)
```

**Option B**

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

// Ask the picker for its preferred size
let datePickerPreferredSize = datePicker.systemLayoutSizeFitting(view.bounds.size)
// Set the frame using that size
datePicker.frame = .init(x: 20, y: 100, width: datePickerPreferredSize.width, height: datePickerPreferredSize.height)

view.addSubview(datePicker)
```