# How to set UIDatePicker background color to white in xamarin.ios for ios 14?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am hiding a label by a UIDatePicker in a xamarin.ios app. I changed the style of the datepicker label but can't change the background to white. Here is my code:

```
            datePickerDateFrom.Frame = lblFromDate.Frame;
            datePickerDateFrom.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].SetValueForKey(UIColor.White, new NSString("backgroundColor"));
            datePickerDateFrom.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].TintColor = UIColor.Black;
            datePickerDateFrom.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            datePickerDateFrom.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Layer.CornerRadius = 6;
            datePickerDateFrom.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 184, 212).CGColor;

            datePickerDateFrom.SizeToFit();
            Add(datePickerDateFrom);
```

And the result is:
[image]

Any other color works but if I set the color to white it remains this ash color that's why sometimes there is a color difference inside the blue border when the short date format is selected. I don't know is it possible to align the value inside the frame and specify any fixed date format(as sometimes it displays 3 letter of month name when gets larger space). For now changing the background color to white would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to your code, I want to know whether your project is Xamarin.Forms->IOS project or Xamarin.ios project. When I ran to "datePickerDateFrom.Subviews[0].Subviews[0]", the system reported an error, so I am not sure what your datePickerDateFrom represents. Is it convenient to show more code or leave your complete project for testing?

Comment: it is  Xamarin.ios project

Comment: As a work-around, make a UIColor that is close to white, but not quite white. See if that works.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770832/199364.  Set Frame's width/height to the calculated/preferred bounds, AFTER the call to `SizeToFit`. Get x and y from lblFromDate, but width and height from ... - use one of the two options in that link. If that doesn't completely hide the label underneath, then either hide the label while datepicker is showing, or cover the label with a borderless white box, underneath the datepicker.